# Find All Word between < and > with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to find word between `<` and `>` from a String.

For example:

```
String str=your mobile number is <A> and username is <B> thanks <C>;
```

I want to get `A`, `B`, `C` from the String.

I have tried

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
     String example = your mobile number is <A> and username is <B> thanks <C>;
     Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\<([^)]+)\\>").matcher(example);
     while(m.find()) {
       System.out.println(m.group(1));    
     }
  }
}
```

What's wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Do you prefer to have solution with the short range `<phone <`**876-5432**`>` or the long rang `<`**My nymber is <876-5432**`>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following idiom and back-reference to get the values for your `A`, `B` and `C` placeholders:

```
String example = "your mobile number is <A> and username is <B> thanks <C>";
//                           ┌ left delimiter - no need to escape here
//                           | ┌ group 1: 1+ of any character, reluctantly quantified
//                           | |   ┌ right delimiter
//                           | |   |
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<(.+?)>").matcher(example);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
A
B
C
```

**Note**

If you favor a solution with no indexed back-reference, and "look-arounds", you can achieve the same with the following code:

```
String example = "your mobile number is <A> and username is <B> thanks <C>";
//                            ┌ positive look-behind for left delimiter
//                            |    ┌ 1+ of any character, reluctantly quantified
//                            |    |   ┌ positive look-ahead for right delimiter
//                            |    |   |
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=<).+?(?=>)").matcher(example);
while (m.find()) {
    // no index for back-reference here, catching main group
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

I personally find the latter less readable in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `>` or `<>` inside the negated character class. `[^)]+` in your regex matches any charcater but not of `)`, one or more times. So this would match also the `<` or `>` symbols.

```
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<([^<>]+)>").matcher(example);
 while(m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
 }
```

OR

Use lookarounds.

```
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=<)[^<>]*(?=>)").matcher(example);
 while(m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example = "your mobile number is <A> and username is <B> thanks <C>";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\<(.+?)\\>").matcher(example);
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works, I tried it. But you can simplify the regex to: ``<(.+?)>``